# Is "America" an example of markedness?

Tags: adjectives

There are North America, Central America, and South America. And, even within North America, there are the USA and Canada. Yet, in US English, if you mention "America" that means the USA.

I am almost certain that UK English has "America" refer exclusively to the USA.

Am I understanding the term "markedness" correctly? What is the correct way to phrase the property of markedness?
"The word, 'America', has the property of markedness."?
"The word, 'America', is a marked word."?

btw: "Dollar" appears to also have markedness. Regardless of the type of English, without need for clarification, a "dollar" is a "US dollar". right?

[explanation of "markedness"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/what-is-markedness)

Comment: As regards the dollar, it very much depends where you are. If you were in Australia and you said dollar, the presumption would be that you were speaking about the Australian dollar. Similarly with New Zealand, Singapore, Hong Kong, Canada, and no doubt a lot of other places. I don't know what you mean by *markedness*.

Comment: Ask yourself this: if you were in one of the places in the world where they shout "Death to America," would you think they meant Central America?

Comment: @ws2 "Markedness" is explained in the Linguistics forum on stack exchange. Just type into the search box over in the linguistics forum: "what is markedness".

Comment: I believe it's pronounced "Murrica".

Comment: WS2 is right about "dollars." I live in Australia, and if a local fruit vendor claimed his prices were in American dollars, I'd assume he was either crazy or trying to scam me.

Comment: In general, reference to "markedness" means a system where there is a default ("unmarked") case and several other "marked" (i.e, special) cases. Keeping track of marked cases is generally considered more expensive (in attention, parsing, effort, etc) than simply using the unmarked case automatically. It's a term used in phonology, morphology, syntax, semantics, and pragmatics; at least. The concept (same as "default") is sufficiently general that practically anything can be used as an example, if it's described in the proper way.

Comment: A careful author/speaker would use the word "America" with care, given that it applies to two continents (plus a small bit of Antarctica).  I try to use "US" to the extent that sentence construction will facilitate it without awkwardness.

Comment: @JohnLawler yeah, I reversed it. "America" is unmarked. In countries that don't call their own currency a "dollar", "dollar" is unmarked. got it.

Comment: @HotLicks I am totally with you there. It bothers me how people use the term "America". Anyway, glad we agree.

Comment: You do not seem to be using the term markedness correctly. I don't think it really applies to a noun like this. Instead you should be looking at implications and connotations.

Comment: It is the custom that if you chose the answer, you might also consider upvoting it. Unless you found that the answer is terrible but nonetheless the best answer.

Comment: @BlessedGeek At the time, I didn't have enough credentials to upvote.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Markedness is all about multiple things and their relation to each other (which one is the default/more natural), but you have only mentioned the word 'America'. What do you want to compare 'America' against? The US? USA? The States? Also, which set of speakers is this about? People from the US? People from the UK? Non-native speakers of English?  People from Europe speaking English? People from South America speaking English? There's lots here for you to choose first before we can answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. Thanks to the efforts of you and others I now understand what *markedness* is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Markedness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness) is a term of comparison:

> Markedness, a term that originated in linguistics, is the state of
> standing out as unusual or difficult **in comparison** to a more
> common or regular form. In a marked–unmarked relation, one term of an
> opposition is the broader, dominant one. The dominant default or
> minimum effort form is known as the unmarked form; and the other,
> secondary one is the marked. In other words, markedness involves the
> characterization of a "normal" linguistic unit against the unit's
> possible "irregular" forms.
>
> *from en.wikipedia.org*

- *Lion* is ***unmarked***, because it is the general term that applies to
  all lions. *Lioness* is ***marked***, because it refers to a specific subset
  of lions.
- *Honesty* is ***unmarked***, because it is the root word. *Dishonesty* is *marked*, because it has a morphological marker.
- *Old* is ***unmarked***, because it is the general term used for our scale of age. We ask how *old* is she as the default. *Young* is ***marked***, because it refers to a specific range on the scale. We don't ask how *young* is she, unless we are specifically drawing attention to her youth.
- *Old* is also ***unmarked***, because it is the term used for elderly people. *Older* is ***marked***, because when we say: *She's old,* her reply is: *No! I'm not old, I'm older!* But on the unmarked scale *older* would be *older* than *old*!

> *Markedness* depends on context. What is more marked in some general
> contexts may be less marked in other local contexts. Thus, "ant" is
> less marked than "ants" on the morphological level, but on the
> semantic (and frequency) levels it may be more marked since ants are
> more often encountered many at once than one at a time.
>
> *from en.wikipedia.org*

In comparing *America* to *America*, the context determines *markedness*:

- Generally, *America* is ***unmarked***, when it refers to all of the territory in the western hemisphere, but it is ***marked*** when it refers to North America or the USA.
- In some contexts, *America* is ***unmarked***, when it refers to the continent of North America , but it is ***marked*** when it refers to the USA.
- In the United States, it could be said that *America* is ***unmarked***, when it refers to the USA, and it is ***marked*** when it refers to North America or all of the territory in the western hemisphere.

In almost all contexts, *dollar* would refer to a specific currency where no other dollar is *marked* in comparison. On the other hand, since the US Dollar is the default currency on the international market, it can be said that *the dollar* is ***unmarked***, and all other dollars are ***marked*** by their national connection, as well as their relationship to the US Dollar:

> $10 US Dollars currently equals:
>
> Australian Dollar: $10.88
>
> Bahamian Dollar: $10.00
>
> Barbadian Dollar: $20.00
>
> Belize Dollar: $20.00
>
> Bermudan Dollar: $10.00
>
> Brunei Dollar: $12.68
>
> Canadian Dollar: $10.52
>
> Eastern Caribbean Dollar: $27.00
>
> Fijian Dollar: $18.74
>
> Guyana Dollar: $2,000.50
>
> Hong Kong Dollar: $77.55
>
> Jamaican Dollar: $1,007.00
>
> Liberian Dollar: $745.00
>
> Namibian Dollar: $99.00
>
> New Zealand Dollar: $12.82
>
> Singapore Dollar: $12.67
>
> Solomon Islands Dollar: $71.40
>
> Surinamese Dollar: $32.75
>
> Taiwanese Dollar: $300.12
>
> Trinidad and Tobago Dollar: $62.51
>
> Zimbabwe Dollar: $3,748.00
>
> from jaunted.com/ [As of July 8,2013](http://www.jaunted.com/story/2013/7/5/14359/15874/travel/21+Other+Countries+That+Use+Dollars+as+Currency)

Comment: I assume you got it [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness), since I can't find any other source citing *honesty, dishonesty* as an "unmarked, marked" pair. I think I need some convincing about that. You can talk about levels of honesty, or dishonesty, and *either* could in principle encompass the entire cline. And either can also be used of just one end of the continuum - *"She is known for honesty"*, *"He is known for dishonesty"*.

Comment: Context is everything when it comes to markedness! I chose honesty as the unmarked because dishonesty has a morphological marker.

Comment: Actually it looks more like... [The unmarked member is the one used in questions of degree. We ask, ordinarily, “how high is the mountain?” {not “how low is it?”}](http://www.slideshare.net/Andriyanieka12/13-semantics-synonym-antonym-homonym-hyponym-polyseme-idioms-18509523) By the same token, we'd usually ask *"How honest is he?"*. Though to be honest I think it impugns the subject of the enquiry almost as much as *"How **dishonest** is he?"*.

Comment: The markedness of honesty and dishonesty is not so clearly a matter of degree, so high/low would be a better example.

Comment: @Fumble Apart from semantics, _honest_ is **morphologically** unmarked and _dishonest_ marked, just like _sit_ is morphologically unmarked (plain form) and _sat_ marked (past tense).

Comment: *Dollar* originates from the German coin *thaler* in the 16th century.

Comment: Germany rules the world after all!

Comment: @Janus: I see now that "marked/unmarked" status can vary by context. Personally I can't imagine using ***America*** to refer to *all of the territory in the western hemisphere* - to me that would have to be plural ***The Americas***. Nor would I be likely to use the single word to include both the USA and Canada, since that would almost always be ***North America***. By the same token, to me *Canadians* aren't a subset of *Americans* (I guess they're a subset of ***North** Americans*, but that's not a demonym I'd expect to use in the first place).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have exactly expressed my initial observation. It bothers me that "America" is assumed "USA" because the world does not revolve around the USA. "America" should have a broader meaning. Yet, that "America" means "USA" just is what it is. So, my way to explain this is to place the blame of "markedness", and not on US self-centeredness.

Comment: @dwakam: Well, from my perspective, unqualified *America* always means *The USA*, so it's not the same as "unmarked" ***dog*** (which can either mean *any canine* or specifically the *male dog* as opposed to a *femmale dog, bitch*).